# Concatenar un string con un float C++

Tags: c++, string

Tengo un problema al concatenar una variable tipo string con una float, tengo lo siguiente:

```
float c1 = 0, c2 = 0, c3 = 0;
std::string best = "";
```

Luego la uso de la siguiente manera:

```
best = "Imagen 1: " + c1;
best = "Imagen 2: " + c2;
best = "Imagen 3: " + c3;
```

Sin embargo me lanza los siguientes errores:

```
../src/Test.cpp:91:24: error: invalid operands of types ‘const char [11]’ and ‘float’ to binary ‘operator+’
    best = "Imagen 1: "+c1;
                        ^
../src/Test.cpp:93:24: error: invalid operands of types ‘const char [11]’ and ‘float’ to binary ‘operator+’
    best = "Imagen 2: "+c2;
                        ^
../src/Test.cpp:95:24: error: invalid operands of types ‘const char [11]’ and ‘float’ to binary ‘operator+’
    best = "Imagen 3: "+c3;
```

**¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En C++11, puedes utilizar el método `to_string` así:

```
best = "Imagen 1: " + std::to_string(c1);
best = "Imagen 2: " + std::to_string(c2);
best = "Imagen 3: " + std::to_string(c3);
```

Antes de C++11, se podía hacer con `stringstream`:

```
#include <sstream>

std::stringstream ss;

ss << "Imagen 1: " << std::to_string(c1);
best = ss.str();

ss.str(std::string());

ss << "Imagen 1: " << std::to_string(c2);
best = ss.str();

ss.str(std::string());

ss << "Imagen 1: " << std::to_string(c3);
best = ss.str();

ss.str(std::string());
```

O mejor como dijo @Peregring-lk, puedes crear un método para hacerlo cuanto quieras:

```
#include <sstream>

std::string floatToString(const float& val) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << val;
    return ss.str();
} 

best = "Imagen 1: " + floatToString(c1);
best = "Imagen 2: " + floatToString(c2);
best = "Imagen 3: " + floatToString(c3);
```

Comment: Si lo intente, pero me sale el siguiente error: “to_string” isn't a member of “std”?

Comment: Ah, entonces no está usando C++11...

Comment: ¿Y que tal con los cambios que hice?

Comment: Gracias, era que no estaba usando C++11 solucione el error: “to_string” isn't a member of “std”, colocando al momento de compilar la sentencia `-std=c++11` me sirvió tu respuesta, Gracias!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <sstream>

std::ostringstream oss;
oss << c1;
best = "Imagen 1" + c1.str();
```

Y así para cada conversión que quieras hacer. Lo mejor es create tu propio método:

```
#include <sstream>

std::string f2string(const float& val)
{
    std::ostringstream os;

    os << val;

    return os.str();
}

best = "Imagen 1" + f2string(c1);
best = "Imagen 2" + f2string(c2);
best = "Imagen 3" + f2string(c3);
```

Comment: Gracias, tambien es una buena alternativa :). +1